# Issue trying to test a Controller that have a Services that have a Repository (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit4

I'm trying to build a test to the `ClienteController.java` that uses the `ClienteService.java` that use `ClienteRepository.java` to the `Cliente.class`

I'm running the tests using the `mvn test` command.

So I am trying to use the `WebMvcTest` to isolate the tests to the web layer. 
I'm following this example that works without the repository on the stack([Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/))

### Code

#### ClienteController.java

```
@Controller
public class ClientesController {

    private final String view = "clientes";

    @Autowired
    ClienteService clienteService;

    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    public ModelAndView clientes() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(view);
        mv.addObject("listar", true);
        mv.addObject("clientes", this.clienteService.listarClientes());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

#### ClienteService.java

```
@Service
public class ClienteService {

    private final ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ClienteService(ClienteRepository clienteRepository) {
        this.clienteRepository = clienteRepository;
    }

    public List<Cliente> listarClientes(){
        return clienteRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

#### ClienteREpository.class

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.id = ?1")
    Cliente findOne(Integer clienteId);
}
```

#### ClientesControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ClientesController.class)
public class ClientesControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @Test
    public void contexLoads() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

### Error

---

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clienteService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.ufpr.sistemapedidos.services.ClienteService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.ufpr.sistemapedidos.services.ClienteService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 1):

See documentation:

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

In particular, `@Service` beans are not configured. The assumption is that `@WebMvcTest` is used to test mvc layer only, and everything else should be mocked. You should mock your `ClienteService` and test is separately, possibly with a unit test. Alternatively, you can use `@SpringBootTest` if you want to configure entire application, or you can simply `@Import` the missing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use mockito and mock all classes and methods that you need. On the example below I am mocking the class Cliente with @Mock and creating the instance of ClienteController with @InjectMocks where the mocks will be injected. Everything is happening only related to the method test, nothing more than that. There is no Spring context in this case.

```
public class ClienteControllerTest {

@Rule 
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@InjectMocks
private ClienteController clienteController;

@Mock
private Cliente mockCliente;

@Test
public void test_salvarCliente_success() {

    try {
        doNothing().when(this.mockCliente).salvarCliente(org.mockito.Mockito.any(Cliente.class));
    } catch (ExcecaoRetorno e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ResponseEntity response = this.clienteController.salvarCliente(new ClienteDto());

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
}
```

}

That is a simple example you can use.